# How to insert a set to a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let us suppose that I need to `insert` 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h' as values of `t1.c1`. This is a possibility:

```
insert into t1(c1, c2, c3)
values
('a', 'c2val', 'c3val'),
('b', 'c2val', 'c3val'),
('c', 'c2val', 'c3val'),
('d', 'c2val', 'c3val'),
('e', 'c2val', 'c3val'),
('f', 'c2val', 'c3val'),
('g', 'c2val', 'c3val'),
('h', 'c2val', 'c3val');
```

However, if I intend to `insert` these into the `table` using an `insert`-`select`, then this will throw a syntax error:

```
insert into t1(c1, c2, c3)
select ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h') as c1, t2.c2, t2.c3
from t2
where t2.c2 > t2.c3;
```

Instead, I have(**?**) to do it individually:

```
insert into t1(c1, c2, c3)
select 'a' as c1, t2.c2, t2.c3
from t2
where t2.c2 > t2.c3;

insert into t1(c1, c2, c3)
select 'b' as c1, t2.c2, t2.c3
from t2
where t2.c2 > t2.c3;

insert into t1(c1, c2, c3)
select 'c' as c1, t2.c2, t2.c3
from t2
where t2.c2 > t2.c3;

insert into t1(c1, c2, c3)
select 'd' as c1, t2.c2, t2.c3
from t2
where t2.c2 > t2.c3;

insert into t1(c1, c2, c3)
select 'e' as c1, t2.c2, t2.c3
from t2
where t2.c2 > t2.c3;

insert into t1(c1, c2, c3)
select 'f' as c1, t2.c2, t2.c3
from t2
where t2.c2 > t2.c3;

insert into t1(c1, c2, c3)
select 'g' as c1, t2.c2, t2.c3
from t2
where t2.c2 > t2.c3;

insert into t1(c1, c2, c3)
select 'h' as c1, t2.c2, t2.c3
from t2
where t2.c2 > t2.c3;
```

I had to write a LOT of this kind of stuff today and I wonder whether I could have done better with using the values as a set instead of writing an `insert`-`select` for each individual value.

EDIT:

'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h' is not my actual data, which is in fact quite ugly and random. The letters were used solely as an example and we should not rely on their particular attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not really sure what the issue is, would this work?

```
insert into t1(c1, c2, c3)
select c1, c2, c3
from 
  (select
    c2, c3
  from
    t2
  where c2 > c3) cross join
(select 'a' as c1 union
select 'b' union
select 'c' union
select 'd' union
select 'e' union
select 'f' union
select 'g' union
select 'h' ) a
```

are you asking how to create a set given a bunch of ugly and random values?  If so, you can either put them in a table or just `union` them together.

Comment: Just what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

This answer uses a [CROSS JOIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690.aspx) which creates a [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) between the user defined data (*letter values in this example*) and the filtered data from table `t2`.

```
DECLARE @inMemTable as TABLE (someValue varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @inMemTable(someValue) values ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D')

INSERT INTO t1(c1, c2, c3)
SELECT letters.someValue as c1, t2.c2, t2.c3
FROM t2 CROSS JOIN @inMemTable as letters
WHERE t2.c2 > t2.c3
```

Comment: The letters were just examples. The inputs in my case were random data.

Comment: @LajosArpad - then you should update your question to clarify that. Either way you need a cross join between a list of values and the filtered content if you want to insert every possible combination.

Comment: @LajosArpad - I updated my answer. Using an table parameter you can define pieces of data and then cross join that with your other table to still produce a record for every possible combination.

Comment: This looks like a solution. I will accept the other answer, but upvoted this one as well, since this is constructive and helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your values clause as a derived table.

```
Select * from (
values
('a', 'c2val', 'c3val'),
('b', 'c2val', 'c3val'),
('c', 'c2val', 'c3val'),
('d', 'c2val', 'c3val'),
('e', 'c2val', 'c3val'),
('f', 'c2val', 'c3val'),
('g', 'c2val', 'c3val'),
('h', 'c2val', 'c3val')
) t(c1,c2,c3)
```

This will give you your set of value as a table on which you can apply as many conditions as you want.